# desvio padrão de todos os elementos de uma matriz no MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Como calcular o desvio padrão de todos os elementos de uma matriz?

a função std divide por coluna.Como faz pra calcular por todos os elementos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada uma matriz `a`, você sempre pode acessar todos os elementos usando `a(:)`.

Exemplo:

```
a=magic(3)
a =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

a(:)
ans =
     8
     3
     4
     1
     5
     9
     6
     7
     2
```

No seu caso, basta usar `std(a(:))` ou invés de `std(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
soma = 0;
soma = a(:,:) + soma; %Basta informar as dimensões da matriz

n = size(a);
media = (soma / n);
s = 0;

% a fórmula de desvio padrão deve ser conferida e testada. 

for i = 1: n

   s = (( a(x) - media )^2)
end

s = ( ( s / (n-1) ) ^ 0.5 )
```

Comment: Olá, você poderia esclarecer um pouco melhor a sua metodologia?

Comment: Olá Wellington, além de um código, uma explicação (mesmo que breve) do que seu código faz ajuda o dono da pergunta, assim como outros usuários que venham a ter o mesmo problema ou algo similar que esta pergunta possa resolver.
 
Além disso, o seu código não funciona com seu exemplo. `n` é uma matriz, se `soma` é apenas a soma de todos os pontos (o que seu código não mostra), isto retorna um erro (Matrix dimensions must agree).

Comment: Note que dividindo por (n-1) tem-se o desvio padrão amostral. Se a matriz original continha todos os possíveis resultados equiprováveis de um experimento dever-se-ia dividir por n. A pergunta original não é clara quanto à isso.